# Quickcheck on custom datatype

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I succesfully run a quickcheck on this:

```
testaroo = quickCheck $ checkWin

checkWin :: [(Int, ThePlayers)] -> Bool
checkWin [(1,_),(2,_),(3,_)] = True
checkWin [(4,_),(5,_),(6,_)] = True
checkWin [(7,_),(8,_),(9,_)] = True
checkWin [(1,_),(5,_),(9,_)] = True
checkWin [(3,_),(5,_),(7,_)] = True
checkWin [(1,_),(4,_),(7,_)] = True
checkWin [(2,_),(5,_),(8,_)] = True
checkWin [(3,_),(6,_),(9,_)] = True
checkWin _ = False
```

but when i try to run

```
testaroo = quickCheck $ removeFromList

removeFromList :: (Int, ThePlayers) -> [(Int, ThePlayers)] -> [(Int, ThePlayers)]
removeFromList tuple list = delete tuple list
```

I run into the following:

```
No instance for (Arbitrary ThePlayers)
      arising from a use of `quickCheck'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Arbitrary ThePlayers)
    In the expression: quickCheck
    In the expression: quickCheck $ removeFromList
    In an equation for `testaroo':
        testaroo = quickCheck $ removeFromList
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What I did to run my quickCheck on checkWin successfully I added

```
instance Arbitrary BoardState
    where
    arbitrary  = arbitrary
```

But in all honesty I'm not quite sure what this does :). Is there anyway I can make the test run on my `removeFromList` function?

Comment: It looks like you are not using `ThePlayers` in `checkWin`. Why not just check for a win on only the `Int` values? You could convert `[(Int, ThePlayers)]` to `[Int]` with `map fst`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QuickCheck has to generate random cases to test against your property, by

```
No instance for (Arbitrary ThePlayers)
```

It basically said it doesn't know how to generate a random `ThePlayers` value for the tests and you should implement an instance `Arbitrary ThePlayers`.

---

Also the type of `quickCheck` is

```
quickCheck :: Testable prop => prop -> IO ()
```

Even if the module can generate random arguments for you, the function `removeFromList` doesn't look like a `Testable` (a property), neither `checkWin`: A property of a function is about: what is supposed to be the right result of it? What should the results satisfy? What's the relationship between arguments and the results? The QuickCheck module won't and can't generate property from your functions, you have to specify it yourself.

(BTW your first test on `checkWin` got compiled only because it have a return type `Bool` by chance, it isn't indicating any property of your program and will fail almost every time)

For example one property of `reverse` function from `Data.List` is: *the `reverse` function should not change the length of the list*, so a check based on this fact shoud be:

```
prop_length :: [Int] -> Bool
prop_length as = length as == length (reverse as)
```

and then you can build a test based on it:

```
test_propLength = quickCheck prop_length
```

---

You may try [some tutorials](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/pbv/an-introduction-to-quickcheck-testing) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

[`Arbitrary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.8.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#v:arbitrary) is a typeclass with one function `arbitrary` you have to implement. As the documentation says:

> ```
> arbitrary :: Gen a
> ```
>
> A generator for values of the given type.

`Gen` is a monad that allows you to construct a "*random*" value. *QuickCheck* will use this to generate random instances in order to generate random lists `[(Int, ThePlayers)]` to test the property.

Since you do not show the definition for `data ThePlayers` we can only guess how to generate an arbitrary value.

An example might be:

```
data Foo = Positive Int | Coordinate Int Int | Character Char

instance Arbitrary Foo where
    arbitrary = oneof [arbitraryPositive,arbitraryCoordinate,arbitraryCharacter]
        where arbitraryPositive = do
                  p <- arbitrary
                  return $ Positive $ abs p
              arbitraryCoordinate = do
                  x <- arbitrary
                  y <- arbitrary
                  return $ Coordinate x y
              arbitraryCharachter = do
                  c <- arbitrary
                  return $ Character c
```